# Does anyone know of a library in Java that can parse ESRI Shapefiles?

Tags: java, shapefile, geotools

I'm interested in writing a visualization program for the road data in the [2009 Tiger/Line Shapefiles](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2009/documentation.html).  I'd like to draw the line data to display all the roads for my county.

> The ESRI Shapefile or simply a
>   shapefile is a popular geospatial
>   vector data format for geographic
>   information systems software. It is
>   developed and regulated by ESRI as a
>   (mostly) open specification for data
>   interoperability among ESRI and other
>   software products.[1](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2009/documentation.html) A "shapefile"
>   commonly refers to a collection of
>   files with ".shp", ".shx", ".dbf", and
>   other extensions on a common prefix
>   name (e.g., "lakes.*"). The actual
>   shapefile relates specifically to
>   files with the ".shp" extension,
>   however this file alone is incomplete
>   for distribution, as the other
>   supporting files are required.

Does anyone know of existing libraries for parsing and reading in the line data for [Shapefiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile)?

Comment: https://github.com/delight-im/Java-Shapefile-Parser

Answer (score 79):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org/) will do it.  There are a ton of jars and you don't need most of them.  However, reading the shapefile is just a few lines.

```
File file = new File("mayshapefile.shp");

try {
  Map<String, String> connect = new HashMap();
  connect.put("url", file.toURI().toString());

  DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connect);
  String[] typeNames = dataStore.getTypeNames();
  String typeName = typeNames[0];

  System.out.println("Reading content " + typeName);

  FeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
  FeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures();
  FeatureIterator iterator = collection.features();


  try {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Feature feature = iterator.next();
      GeometryAttribute sourceGeometry = feature.getDefaultGeometryProperty();
    }
  } finally {
    iterator.close();
  }

} catch (Throwable e) {}
```

Comment: if you use Maven to compile the program it handles all the jars for you.

Comment: Geotools has great tutorial on how to start development. It's a Swing application for visualizing a map http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/netbeans.html

Comment: This answers example is excellent, saved me having to deep dive into the API docs

Answer (score 9):

[Openmap](http://openmap.bbn.com/) has a [Java API](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/dataAccess/shape/package-summary.html) that provides read and write access to ESRI files.

Comment: Note that although BBN's OpenMap is open source, it uses a weird BBN-specific license.  It's pretty permissive, but the fact that it's not a standard license may cause issues when trying to combine it with other software (or when attempting to get it approved by your legal beagles).

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use said API to read an ESRI file? OpenMap's API is opaque and utterly baffling to me.

Comment: Note that [Openmap](http://openmap-java.org/) has been relocated.

Answer (score 6):

There is [GeoTools](http://geotools.org), or more exactly this class [ShapefileDataStore](http://geotools.org/javadocs/org/geotools/data/shapefile/ShapefileDataStore.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use [Java ESRI Shape File Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javashapefilere/) library. It's small, easy to install  and has very simple API.
The only drawback is that it does not read other mandatory and optional files (.shx, .dbf, etc.) that are usually shipped with a shape file.

Comment: Do you know any other small easy to use library for this case- reading .shx and .dbf ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use GUI GIS tools so that their is no need of changing the source code of GeoTools.

I use QGIS which does all operations(even more) than GeoTools.

[Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org) - An open source Geographic Information System for editing, merging and simplifying shapefile maps. See also: creating maps with multiple layers using Quantum GIS.