# To access shape files in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, shapefile

How to access shape files in android, please provide any tutorial or library?

Comment: you can apply shapes on view select from drawable

Comment: by "access shape file" you mean you need a parser for it?

Comment: Looks like [this][1] link is highly relevant to what you're looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044876/does-anyone-know-of-a-library-in-java-that-can-parse-esri-shapefiles